# Ollydbg Reverse Engineering IP Address

Tags: ollydbg

I'm trying to reverse engineer an old game that I used to fiddle around with that is no longer being maintained. Currently, I'm just trying to edit the connection IP to fake that the server is online, but I've had some problems tracking down the IP within the application. After doing a wireshark test, the IP Address that the program tries to connect to is: 24.56.108.156, but doing a scan for that with a hex editing program(XVI32 specifically) in hex or text returns no result.

So, I continued to fiddle and loaded up ollydbg which I haven't used forever and my knowledge of assembly has plummeted no doubt. Anyway, I first looked into the referenced strings and found some text left in there (code comments it seems) that shows that the "RemoteHostIP" function returns the IP of the remote host. So, I found the assembly to the call and did a breakpoint on it to make sure it was the correct function and it is called right when the client tries to connect. The assembly for it is:

`MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[C98FA8]

OR EAX, EAX 

JE SHORT Eternal.0043629F //Jumps back to the MOV call.`

I looked at the value of EAX and it shows to be 75843918 and the DS is 002B, but the EAX value(when converted back to decimal or ascii) is not equal to the IP address that the client tries to connect too. So, I have no clue what exactly DS means other than Data segment register or how it effects the de-referenced pointer, so I went to the expression 00C98FA8 and got the same value of 75843918 which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm running out of ideas over here, is there anything specific I could have missed? Does that DS have some effect that I don't know about? Any help would be greatly appreciated and if I left out some information that could be helpful, just tell me.

--Newly Added Information-- 
In response to typ1232 and just for more information:

The address has some padding between the individual numbers, it went like:
32, Random Number Of 00s and other junk ..etc, so I cannot track it down directly.

Comment: are you sure the IP is hardcoded, maybe DNS is used ?

Comment: Positive its hardcoded, I was able to find it not to long ago. However, I totally forgot how I found it.

Comment: On Windows, all the segment registers are 0, so they have no effect on the address (except FS which is used for thread local storage). If the IP is really hardcoded you should be able to find the byte sequence `18 38 6c 9c` or `9c 6c 38 18` (not sure about order).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, StackExchange has another site, dedicate to the topic of reverse engineering. Just thinking that you might get a better response if you brought your question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding it with some guessing, it seems that each piece of the application split things with an 00 before every piece of the ip, so it turned out to be: 00 32 00 34 00 2E etc and so on.

Comment: I'm googling around on primers for reverse engineering using OllyDBG, came across this and your answer. The 00XX00XX00XX format is telling of the use of Unicode! Your IP address appears to be in Unicode, which uses two bytes per character, thus it pads 00 in front of ASCII characters because ASCII characters are first in the Unicode table. Woo!

Comment: unicode in Windows is UTF-16 (16-bit / 2 byte fixed length)